# using cmd or powershell, calling python file returns no output

Tags: python

I've just installed python 2.7.2 on this machine. 
I'm attempting to run this code:

```
class Hello(object):
    def main(self):
        print "hello world"

if __name__ == "main":
    h = Hello()
    h.main()
```

When I call it with python ./foo.py, it does not return either a print statement or log statement, just what appears to be a newline.

When I call it from a python shell it works as expected.

Additionally, I could write the file:

```
print "hello world"
```

And that will print in either powershell or cmd.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `if __name__ == "__main__":`. You forgot the underscores around `main`.